# Cannot found libc/machine/arm/libc_a-setjmp.o when building Newlib with Clang 15.0.0

Tags: newlib

I was building Newlib with my custom LLVM passes.

#### Problem

When building Newlib, it reported an error:

```
  AR       libc.a
/mnt/storage/2022DualCoreIsolation/DualCoreIsolationProject/llvm15_0/build/bin/llvm-ar: error: libc/machine/arm/libc_a-setjmp.o: No such file or directory
```

I checked that the source file `setjmp.S` exists:

```
newlib/ $ ls libc/machine/arm/setjmp.S
libc/machine/arm/setjmp.S
```

But other files are built into .o files. For example, source file `libc/machine/arm/memchr-stub.c` is compiled into `arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/machine/arm/libc_a-memchr-stub.o`

#### Environmental Settings

The toolchains:

```
Newlib: tag newlib-4.3.0
LLVM: 15.0.0
arm-none-eabi-gcc: (15:10.3-2021.07-4) 10.3.1 20210621 (release)
```

The configure options for Newlib:

```
"$NEWLIB_SRC/configure" --target="arm-none-eabi"                            \
                        --srcdir="$NEWLIB_SRC"                              \
                        --prefix="$NEWLIB_INSTALL"                          \
                        --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls                  \
                        --with-cpu=armv7m                                   \
                        --with-mode=thumb
```

---

Does someone know how to fix this bug? Thank you in advance!